# Silent install of ArcGIS Pro Add-In

Tags: arcgis-pro, add-in, arcgis-pro-sdk

We are currently migrating to ArcGIS Pro 2.2, with new add-in to improve our workflow.
Our Add-in have been shared on a common network drive so far. But our main concern is that **we are not admin on our machines**, so when we need to install an add-in the IT guy needs to come.

A way to share any add-in and to update them would be a silent install. I found [this thread on Geonet](https://community.esri.com/thread/93990) for ArcGIS desktop. 
The way described is to change the default path to the add-in to a new path with the proper registry key:

> \\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ESRI\Desktop10.2\Settings\AddInFolders and set the value

Is it possible to use the same method for ArcGIS Pro add-in?

Answer (score 2):

In case this help someone else, I contacted the person from the GeoNet thread and here is his answer:

*"In short YES, ArcGIS Pro supports the concept of Shared Add-ins. To have a Add-In load to ArcGIS Pro without user action you need to create a registry setting at:*

```
\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ESRI\ArcGISPro\Settings\Add-in Folders
```

*Create a new REG_SZ key there, the value name is the path to a folder containing your Add-Ins. The value data for the key is null (not set).You can have more than one key. A path would look like:*

```
W:\GIS\TOOLS\Custom\ArcGISPro
```

*In our case we map the W:\ folder on all agency computers and post shared Add-Ins to the above location. If you have access to Visual Studio you can easily build an MSI package or just a simple .bat file to deploy this registry key.
At the folder location defined above you have your add-ins. They are stored in their own subfolder at the above location. The subfolders are named based on the ArcInfo id GUID of the add-in as shown in your Config.daml (note - if you start a new Add-In from a snippet or stub provided by ESRI be sure you update the ArcInfo id in the Config.daml or they will all be the same :-). Also, Add-Ins are loaded by Pro in alphabetical sequence based on the ArcInfo id GUID."*